# Nifi - Issue with Connection in hiveql or executesql

Tags: hiveql, apache-nifi, hdf

I am getting issue with the connection pools, every time I had to disable and enable, then its working.

Can anyone please help.

I have also attached the screenshot. please help.

Thanks.

[connection issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4RD3.png)

Comment: your system connection between sql server installed machine and  nifi running machine doesn't connected.Could you check those both machines can ping or not?

Comment: ya all is fine but when it runs automatically based on scheduling, it throws that error and when we disable and enable its working. So what I had to do everytime is, I need to disable and enable. this is the problem

Comment: What version of NiFi are you using? Which HiveQL processor(s) are you using (SelectHiveQL, PutHiveQL, e.g.) Does the HiveQL processor work for a while and then fail, or does it always fail?

Comment: puthiveql as well as selecthiveql. Its is not always failing.

Comment: ya its works fine for a while and when I try starting the whole flow again it throws the error. For this we had to every time disable and enable the connection pool, then its work fine. what might be the problem, can you please help us on this. thanks.